# Xamarin Forms: when retrieving data, how do you best choose when to use async/await vs a synchronous execution?

Tags: xamarin.forms, async-await, synchronous

I'm feeling I am using async/await too much in my Xamarin Forms project. When should one not to use async/await?

Comment: And why do you feel you are using async/await to much? What are the disadvantages you are experiencing?

Comment: It depends on what you used to receive data, for now, many methods needs to use async await. You could ceck the link below.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming